# Linux kernel version discrepancy

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

This is maybe a basic question.

I am relatively new to Linux and I use Fedora 20. When I run:

```
uname -r
```

command, I get

```
3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
```

When I run:

```
rpm -qa kernel
```

I get:

```
kernel-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
kernel-3.13.10-200.fc20.x86_64
kernel-3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64
```

Regarding this discrepancy, may I please ask some basic questions:

1. What are the differences between the two commands? Don't they both search for the version information of the kernel?
2. What causes that discrepancy?
3. What can I do to correct them?

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the differences between the two commands? Don't they both search for the version information of the kernel?

The first gives the version of the currently running kernel. The second gives the name, version, release, and arch of all kernel packages installed. Two completely different things.

> What causes that discrepancy?

You can only run one kernel at a time, chosen either at boot or via kexec.

> What can I do to correct them?

There is nothing wrong, and hence nothing to correct.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and kind response. I got this question because it's causing problem with VirtualBox running. Could this cause such a problem?

Comment: You haven't described your problem sufficiently for me to be able to answer that.

Comment: Ah, okay, understood. I think that question should be a separate thread. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, a quick question: Why wouldn't my Fedora be running the highest version: 3.14?

Comment: Because you haven't rebooted since installing it. See part 2 of the answer.

Comment: Just to double check, I rebooted. 'uname' still reveals 3.11 not 3.14. I'll try 'kexec' I guess.

Comment: Um... I tried this, but this didn't quite work. (I just started a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706905/make-changes-to-kernel-version)