# Make changes to kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

I am using Fedora 20 and somehow it boots to an older version of the kernel: 3.11, instead of 3.14. `uname -r` shows `3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64` and `rpm -qa kernel` shows `kernel-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64, kernel-3.13.10-200.fc20.x86_64, kernel-3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64`

1. I am curious why this is caused.
2. How I can make it to boot to 3.14 (the updated version.)
3. Would it cause trouble if I remove the older versions?
4. If not, how can I remove the older version, just for the record.

A user from another thread suggested me to hold 'Ctrl' key to change this, but this didn't quite work out and I wish to have more permanent solution to this.

All other thread only mentions how to install and boot to older versions, not the other way around. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting all the kernel version in `GRUB` Screen. if not then update `GRUB` then it will display all the `kernel version` and then you can select as per your choice.

`grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

try above using super user mode.

You should not delete the older kernels as i tried in Debian it made me to format the HD so better keep all versions. You can remove the kernel package but due to dependency and other reasons it may create problems. Still you want to remove the kernels then you can follow the [link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/).

Comment: Thank you for kind and concise help!